# Sharing client variable with Meteor.onCreateUser function on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to share a variable that is set in the client with the Meteor.onCreateUser function call on the server.

I have this code that sets some user properties before a user is created

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user, err) {

    if (options.profile) {

      user.profile = options.profile;

      // Images
      var picturelrg = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
      var picturesm = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=small";

      options.profile.picturelrg = picturelrg;
      options.profile.picturesm = picturesm;
      options.profile.upvotes = 0;
      options.profile.neutralvotes =  0;
      options.profile.downvotes = 0;
      // ip = response.ip;


      return user;
    }
 });
```

Here is the client code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

fbLogin = function() {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
        requestPermissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_location']
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
        // redirect to register if popup comes and user isn't on register
            Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown Eror');
        console.log(Session.get('errorMessage'));
    });
}


locate = function(){

    function ipLocate(whenDone) {
      var api = "http://ipinfo.io?callback=?";
      $.getJSON(api, {
          format: "jsonp"
        })
        .done(function(response) {
          var result = ""

          // show all the props returned
          for (var prop in response) {
            result += prop + ": " + response[prop] + "<br>";
          }

          var selectedResponse = {
            city: response.city,
            region: response.region,
            country: response.country,
            ip: response.ip,
            latLng: response.loc
          }
          console.log(selectedResponse);
          whenDone(selectedResponse);

          return selectedResponse
        });
    }

    // HACK: Async
    function ipDone(selectedResponse) {
      response = selectedResponse;
    }

    // Set response
    ipLocate(ipDone);
    return response
}

Template.ModalJoin.events({
    'click .modJoinFB-Btn ': function() {
    locate();
    fbLogin();
    }
});

}
```

On the client I have an event handler that sets some values when the user clicks the "Sign Up with Facebook" button. How can I send these values to the onCreateUser function to be accessed.

Ex: I want to store user geolocation info ( city, state) when the user registers but I don't know how this can be sent from the client to server.

I'm not sure how I would use Meteor.call() if I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should run a `Meteor.call` function inside `fbLogin`, passing that location data, if no error is returned. Something like this:

```
fbLogin = function() {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
        requestPermissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_location']
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown Eror');
            console.log(Session.get('errorMessage'));
        } else {
            //if no error was returned, then Meteor.call the location
            var userId = Meteor.userId(); //you should send that userId for the method.
            Meteor.call('storeLocation', locationData, userId, function(err,res){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And on server, you create a Method for updating that user profile data with the location. Maybe something like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'storeLocation': function(locationData, userId) {
        var locationData = {
            // based on what you have gathered on your client location function
            'city': response.city,
            'region': response.region,
            'country': response.country,
            'ip': response.ip,
            'latLng': response.loc
        }
        Meteor.users.update(
            //I suggest placing it inside profile, but do as it is better to you
            {'_id': userId},
            {$addToSet: {'profile.locations': locationData }}
        );
    }
});
```

Not sure if you will store like that, but this is how I have done for myself. Let me know if any problems or doubts, we can try to solve it together.

Comment: I had considered this but I thought maybe the Meteor.users.update() would run to early before the user had even been created. I will soon know if this works.

Comment: If it does not work, let me know. I imagine it will because it is triggered just after server retrieves success or error from facebook login. In my experience, nesting a function inside a Meteor.call or any other server call usually works as expected. If it was out of Meteor.loginWithFacebook, then that would be the case you commented. But as it is nested, depending on success, it probably will work.